# Revertendo efeito jquery

Tags: jquery

Estou aprendendo Jquery. E fiz o seguinte codigo

```
$(document).ready(function(){           
    $('html').click(function(){             
        $('.box').css("background-color", "#666");
        $('.box').animate({"width":"400px"}, 1000);             
    });             
});
```

Nesse código ao clicar em qualquer do html é realizado o efeito entra em execução!

Só que tipo, se eu clicar uma vez o efeito executa! Como fazer então para que eu clique de novo o efeito se "reverta"??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você tem duas formas de fazer o que quer:

### 1º método

Existe um comando no jQuery chamado `toggleClass`, você pode usar ele para conseguir o que quer alternando a classe do objeto. Imagine uma div azul, e você quer que fique amarela. Faça ela azul e então crie uma classe para ela ficar amarela. Assim ao clicar aonde for, o jQuery adiciona a nova classe ao objeto, e quando clicar novamente, retira. Exemplo:

```
$("#bloco").click(function() { 
  $(this).toggleClass("outraClasse");
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1ktu8xob/

Lembrando que é importante colocar a propriedade `transition` no elemento, assim você pode controlar o tempo das animações de transição.

### 2º método

Você pode usar esse código JavaScript para criar uma função de variação entre os cliques:

```
(function($) {
$.fn.clickToggle = function(func1, func2) {
    var funcs = [func1, func2];
    this.data('toggleclicked', 0);
    this.click(function() {
        var data = $(this).data();
        var tc = data.toggleclicked;
        $.proxy(funcs[tc], this)();
        data.toggleclicked = (tc + 1) % 2;
    });
    return this;
};
}(jQuery));
```

Assim seu código ficaria assim:

```
$('#bloco').clickToggle(function(){             
    $(this).css("background-color", "#666");
    $(this).animate({"width":"400px"}, 1000);             
}, function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
    $(this).animate({"width":"50px"}, 1000);    
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/shw51knq/

---

### Referência

Código para o 2º método pego dessa resposta: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4911660/3126013

Comment: ! Eu sei que não é o foco do site, mas poderia me indicar algum lugar para aprender mais sobre jquery?

Comment: Olha, vou ser sincero com você, acho que ficar seguindo guia não te leva a nada, pois você não aplica o que aprende (na verdade isso depende muito de você). Te recomendo a dar uma estudada antes em JavaScript, para assim então partir pra um framework (como o jQuery). Eu acho muito bacana (e é como eu estudo a maioria das linguagens de programação) você inventar um projeto e aplicar todo seu conhecimento nele. Quando se deparar com algo que não sabe fazer, google it! A documentação do jQuery é ótima, se estiver com alguma dúvida dê uma olhada nela: https://api.jquery.com/
Bons estudos!